# R - Best format to save simple JSON config

Tags: r, json

I have a JSON config which stores parameters for a process I am running in R. It looks something like this...

```
{
 "param1": true,
 "param2: 5,
 "param3": 'some_string',
 ...
}
```

I want to be able to save this config so that later on we trace what parameters were ran with what process. Obviously I could do this with something likes `writeLines()` and save to a text file, but this opens it up for potential editing. Is there a way to "screenshot" the config such that it saves the info and makes it uneditable?

Comment: You could save the R object resulting from that JSON as an RDS object with `saveRDS`.  Or you could name the file something like `config_DO_NOT_EDIT.json`.

Comment: Not really sure where you "could-be-edited" worries lie and just how difficult you need to make it. Maybe simply writing the `JSON` as a single line would make it hard enough to edit. Or you could lock or password protect the file at the OS level. You could [use the `secrets` package](https://github.com/gaborcsardi/secret#readme) to stash it.

Comment: @GregorThomas It's not super imperative but consider this case... A user runs the process locally and the config is saved as a .json with the other information necessary information. In theory the .json could be accidentally edited and saved where it does not reflect the true config for the process.

Comment: You could use `Sys.chmod(mode="0444")` to only allow reading of the file. Other ideas: print it, or store it in an online storage that provides recovery options a la Time Machine.

Comment: You could also put some sort of checksum at the bottom of the JSON (or even in the file name) so that you could verify it's not been toouched.

Comment: With all that, I'm voting to close this question as opinion-based. It's a bit vague to start, many possibilities have been mentioned, and there's no way for anyone other than OP to begin to outline pros/cons of each method without much more detail about the problem.